# ElementTree python Namesapce prefix

Tags: python, namespaces, prefix, elementtree

Lets consider the example code below:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
treexsdr = ElementTree.parse('anyxml.xml')
iter = treexsdr.getiterator()
for element in iter:
    if element.keys():
        for name, value in element.items():
            k2=element.items()
```

here k2's value will be in form of list of tuples:

```
[("{somenamespace}element","elementValue")... . ]
```

I don't know its namesapce prefix, but here we can assume its:

```
{somenamespace}=abc
```

so is there anyway that i can get as???

```
[("abc:element","elementValue")..  .]
```

here in example i have just assumed it as "abc".... so without knowing namespace prefix, can i apply the same prefix where ever respective namespace url comes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
for index in range(0, len(k2)):
    k2[index].lstrip('{').replace('}',':')
```

Comment: Here, i don't know its prefix, though i can see it when i open it, but here in example i have just assumed it as "abc"....
so without knowing namespace prefix, can i apply the same prefix where ever respective namespace url comes...